# PyUSB/ similar USB functionality for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyusb

Is it possible to get a program like PyUSB, or similar, for python version 2.7?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the problem is - the `PyUSB` [page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyusb/index.php?title=Main_Page) says it supports Python >= 2.4. From other Googled web sources I see people have used it with 2.7 - does it not work for you? What is the exact trouble you're having?

Comment: When I try to run the executable, it says "Python version is not 2.4".. Or something like that..

Comment: @user715578: which executable are you trying to run? pyusb is a Python module, it's not an executable. Maybe you're running the binary installer for 2.4?